# MVC Application can't push email from Model

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to push email notification to an email address immediately the user submits data.

The data should be saved to the database( Working) then automatically the notification is sent.

However from the Model, there is one member that returns an the error.

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Code from Controller:

```
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        customer.ID = 0;
        customer.DateServed = DateTime.Now;
        customer.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
        db.CallCustomers.Add(customer);
        TempData["Message"] = "Added Successfuly";
        ModelState.Clear();

        //SEND NOTIFICATION via mail
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@mail.com"));

        mm.Subject = "Call Notifications";
        mm.Body = customer.Departments.Department;

        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(mm);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
    }

    ViewBag.DepID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepID", "Department", customer.DepID);
    return View(customer);
}
```

Comment: Post the Exception

Comment: You mind, showing us where do you set the `db` member ? you should set it in the controller constructor.

Comment: What is Line 64 in the CustomerController.cs?

Comment: This is line 64 @Lee Stevens  mm.Body = customer.Departments.Department;  The Customer Model is Related to the Department Model ( 1 to Many) in that order

Comment: When you breakpoint that line does `Department` have a value or is it Null?

Comment: Orel Eraki. The db calls the Context Class, and yes it is in the controller constructor         private CallContext db = new CallContext();

Comment: For null reference exceptions (or any exception really) it is suggested that you learn how to read the exception stacktrace to identify the line that's throwing the exception and go from there.

Comment: Lee Stevens - Department is null after a breakpoint

Comment: So the customer.Departments isn’t being populated or set. And that’s why you get the ‘ Object reference not set to an instance of an object.‘ where are you populating/setting the Departments List?

Comment: Department is a table on its own that is related to Customer. In this case Customer contains a foreign key reference to Department

Comment: It's a drop down list

Comment: The select list will only provide you with the department's Id value. You will still have to pull that data from the db in order to actually populate the object. Hopefully I'm reading this right.

Comment: My issue is that  "Customer.Departments.Department" returns an exception error. Apparently it has null values. Departments is the Model(table). DepID is the PK and Department contains the values i want sent via mail. If i withdraw the code related to mailing it just saves without issues